# Data tables filters, search Not functioning mongodb php

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

In this code filter, search and pagination not functioning i have tried myself but it didn't work so please check the code give me any solution or any reference regarding to this query. Even any related to this code files or docs it will be helpful for me to pursue the concept

```
    <?php

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$database   = 'test';
$collection = 'user';

/**
 * MongoDB connection
 */
try{
        // Connecting to server
        $m = new MongoClient(  );
    }catch(MongoConnectionException $connectionException){
        print $connectionException;
        exit;
    }

$m_collection = $m->$database->$collection;    
$input = $fields = $totalRecords = $data = array();
$input = & $_REQUEST;
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'email', 'gender,');

// Input method (use $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST)


/**
 * Handle requested DataProps
 */

// Number of columns being displayed (useful for getting individual column search info)
$iColumns = & $input['iColumns'];

// Get mDataProp values assigned for each table column
$dataProps = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $iColumns; $i++) {
    $var = 'mDataProp_'.$i;
    if (!empty($input[$var]) && $input[$var] != 'null') {
        $dataProps[$i] = $input[$var];
    }
}

$searchTermsAny = array();
$searchTermsAll = array();

if ( !empty($input['sSearch']) ) {
    $sSearch = $input['sSearch'];

    for ( $i=0 ; $i < $iColumns ; $i++ ) {
        if ($input['bSearchable_'.$i] == 'true') {
            if ($input['bRegex'] == 'true') {
                $sRegex = str_replace('/', '\/', $sSearch);
            } else {
                $sRegex = preg_quote($sSearch, '/');
            }
            $searchTermsAny[] = array(
                $dataProps[$i] => new MongoRegex( '/'.$sRegex.'/i' )
            );
        }
    }
}

// Individual column filtering
for ( $i=0 ; $i < $iColumns ; $i++ ) {
    if ( $input['bSearchable_'.$i] == 'true' && $input['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
        if ($input['bRegex_'.$i] == 'true') {
            $sRegex = str_replace('/', '\/', $input['sSearch_'.$i]);
        } else {
            $sRegex = preg_quote($input['sSearch_'.$i], '/');
        }
        $searchTermsAll[ $dataProps[$i] ] = new MongoRegex( '/'.$sRegex.'/i' );
    }
}

$searchTerms = $searchTermsAll;
if (!empty($searchTermsAny)) {
    $searchTerms['$or'] = $searchTermsAny;
}
 $totalRecords =$m_collection->count();
$cursor = $m_collection->find($searchTerms, $fields);

/**
 * Paging
 */
if ( isset( $input['iDisplayStart'] ) && $input['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
    $cursor->limit( $input['iDisplayLength'] )->skip( $input['iDisplayStart'] );
}

/**
 * Ordering
 */
if ( isset($input['iSortCol_0']) ) {
    $sort_fields = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $input['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ ) {
        if ( $input[ 'bSortable_'.intval($input['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == 'true' ) {
            $field = $dataProps[ intval( $input['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ];
            $order = ( $input['sSortDir_'.$i]=='desc' ? -1 : 1 );
            $sort_fields[$field] = $order;
        }
    }
    $cursor->sort($sort_fields);
}


foreach ( $cursor as $doc ) 
{   $name = '<a href="profile.php?secure='.$doc['_id'].' " style = "color:red;">'.$doc['name'].'</a>';
    $data[] = array($name, $doc['email'], $doc['gender]);
}

/**
 * Output
 */
$json_data = array(  
     "draw"=> intval( $input['draw'] ),
   "recordsTotal" =>intval ($totalRecords),
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
    "data"            => $data

);    

echo json_encode( $json_data );
```

---

```
And also i need to Join two tables as given below.
```

Table 1

[image: Table 1]

Table 2

[image: Table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing it like:

```
$('#datatable_emp_details').dataTable({
    "sServerMethod": "POST", 
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "get_data.php"
});
```

get_data.php:

```
<?php
$mongo      = new MongoClient();
$database   = $mongo->selectDb('dbtest');
$collection = $database->selectCollection('empDetails');
$skip       = (int)$_REQUEST['iDisplayStart'];
$limit      = (int)$_REQUEST['iDisplayLength'];
$search     = $_REQUEST['sSearch'];
$sortIndex  = $_REQUEST['iSortCol_0'];

$sortArray  = array('emp_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'position', 'email', 'office', 'start_date', 'age', 'salary', 'projects'
);
$sortByCol  = $sortArray[$sortIndex];
$sortTypeTxt= $_REQUEST['sSortDir_0'];  // asc/desc
$sortType = -1;
if( $sortTypeTxt == 'asc' )
{
    $sortType = 1;
}
if( $search != '' )
{
    $condtion = array(
                    '$or' => array(
                        array('emp_id'    => $search),
                        array('first_name'=> new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),   // i for case insensitive
                        array('last_name' => new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),
                        array('position'  => new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),
                        array('email'     => new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),
                        array('office'    => new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),
                        array('start_date'=> new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),
                        array('age'       => new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),
                        array('salary'    => new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i')),
                        array('projects'  => new MongoRegex('/'. $search .'/i'))
                    )
                );
    $resultSet =   $collection->find($condtion)->limit($limit)->skip($skip)->sort(array($sortByCol => $sortType));
}
else
{
    $resultSet  = $collection->find()->limit($limit)->skip($skip)->sort(array($sortByCol => $sortType))->sort(array($sortByCol => $sortType));
}
$data = array();
if( count( $resultSet ) > 0 )
{
    foreach ($resultSet as $document)
    {
        $data[] = $document;
    }
}
$resultSet  = $collection->find();
$iTotal     = count($resultSet);
$rec = array(
    'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
    'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iTotal,
    'aaData' => array()
);
$k=0;
if (isset($data) && is_array($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $rec['aaData'][$k] = array(
            0  => $item['emp_id'],
            1  => $item['first_name'],
            2  => $item['last_name'],
            3  => $item['position'],
            4  => $item['email'],
            5  => $item['office'],
            6  => $item['start_date'],
            7  => $item['age'],
            8  => $item['salary'],
            9  => $item['projects'],
            10 => '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit_emp" id="'. $item['emp_id'] .'">Edit</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_emp" id="'. $item['emp_id'] .'">Delete</a>'
        );
        $k++;
    }
}
echo json_encode($rec);
exit;
?>
```

[Github repository link](https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-server-side-datatable-with-mongodb-example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Now Search working fine but i can't get the Showing entries and next button properly in there 12 doc in collection but it can showing like this in datatable(**Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries**)and if  i can set 25 it can  showing 12doc ... can help me to get Showing  entries and  next button..

Comment: These two lines `$resultSet  = $collection->find();
$iTotal     = count($resultSet);` are for maintaining the pagination entirely

Comment: now it can working fine ....thank you #mayank i can modifi this code like$resultSet  = $collection->find();
$iTotal     = $resultSet->count(); working fine

Comment: I hope this code helps you, and you are the one who are using datatable just like my way. Otherwise I think only I am using datatable in this way :P

Comment: you can see my code once again i can change my question..if you see above ... if i have two collection how to join two collection in datatable using server side script